# Unable to update the component state in React on the onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to update the state of this component and display a div based on the onclick event. The state never gets updated by the this.setState method, am I doing something wrong?

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

export default class TypeAheadDropdown extends PureComponent {

    state = {
        hasClicked: false
    }
    renderSuggestions = () => {
        return this.props.suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="type-ahead-text" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, suggestion)}>
                {suggestion}
            </div>
        ));
    };

    handleClick = (e, query) => {
        this.props.updateSearchQuery(query);
        this.props.fetchSearchResults(e, query);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            hasClicked: !prevState.hasClicked
        }), () => { console.log(this.state.hasClicked) })
    };

    render() {
        return (this.props.suggestions.length > 0) ? (
            <div className="type-ahead-pane">{this.renderSuggestions()}</div>
        ) : ((!this.state.hasClicked) ?
            <div className="type-ahead-pane">
                <div className="type-ahead-text">
                    No suggestions found for<strong> "{this.props.searchQuery}"</strong>
                </div>
            </div> : null
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you actually get into handleClick? do a console log inside it, if no then try `onClick={() => this.handleClick(e, suggestion)`

Comment: I can get into handleClick(), if I console the state after the setstate, it logs the state, so it's like bypassing the setstate and moving on to the next statement.

Comment: refer to this, you can use componentDidUpdate? https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c

Comment: In the `console.log(this.state.hasClicked)` after your `setState`, is `hasClicked` toggling between `true` and `false`? Based on the code shown, that should be happening.

Comment: this.setState({
            hasClicked: !this.state.hasClicked
        }, () => { console.log(this.state.hasClicked) })